# Wordpress update and plugin install not working

Tags: plugins, updates

I am working on a website that I installed WP on a few months back but haven't worked on beyond the install of WP and a theme. I went back to it today and needed to update WP and install a few plugins.

When I went to do that it started asking me for FTP info, which was new to me. After research I added said FTP info into the wp-config file. Now when I go to update WP or install a plugin, where it should start putting info on the screen about downloading and updating the files I get nothing in the right pane of the dashboard.

I've tried chmod wp-content to 777 and still nothing. I can FTP but I need to be able to update via WP.

I'm stumped. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wordpress is only asking for FTP credentials if your chmod permissions are misconfigured. You should start by checking them. It means all files and directories inside wordpress dir and not only wp-content.

Comment: To isolate the problem I'm only working on adding a plugin now.  Everything is showing 775 for the WP folder, including the plugins folder.  I removed the FTP info from the wp-config file, back to asking for FTP login info.

Comment: Is your apache instance running as the same user as your permissions are set to?

Comment: Checked it and it is using same user permissions.

Comment: Further digging of the hosting company (that gets good reviews but I don't particularly care for) shows others saying you can't use auto updates of WP here and possibly having to use CGIwrap.  Looks like its not a chmod issue but a hosting company issue.  I think your answer will be most helpful to others though and it helped me find my answer, so I am marking it as correct and voting it up.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to update your WordPress installation be sure to disable all your plugins first. I had several problems when i've not disabled these, plugins for backups above all.

Comment: No plugins active